# mysql statement with date filtering not working

Tags: mysql

The following sql is working fine and returns 90 records as expected and also the count is correct but when add date filtering in the sql, it returns only 44 rows instead of 90 but the total count is correct.

sql without date filtering:

```
sql without date filtering:
SELECT
t4.firstname,
t1.category
,COUNT(t3.catid) as days
FROM category AS t1
LEFT JOIN (SELECT 
            DISTINCT empid,t1.catid 
        FROM attendance AS t2 
        LEFT JOIN category AS t1 ON (t1.catid>0)
        ) AS t2 
ON (t1.catid=t2.catid) 
LEFT JOIN attendance AS t3 ON (t2.empid=t3.empid AND t3.catid=t2.catid)
left join employee t4 on t2.empId=t4.empid
GROUP BY t2.empid,t2.catid
ORDER BY t2.empid,t2.catid;
```

with date filtering:

```
SELECT
t4.firstname,
t1.category
,COUNT(t3.catid) as days
FROM category AS t1
LEFT JOIN (SELECT 
            DISTINCT empid,t1.catid 
        FROM attendance AS t2 
        LEFT JOIN category AS t1 ON (t1.catid>0)
        ) AS t2 
ON (t1.catid=t2.catid) 
LEFT JOIN attendance AS t3 ON (t2.empid=t3.empid AND t3.catid=t2.catid)
left join employee t4 on t2.empId=t4.empid
where
date_format(dateIn, '%Y-%m-%d')>=str_to_date("1/01/2015", '%m/%d/%Y')
and date_format(dateout, '%Y-%m-%d')<=str_to_date("12/31/2015", '%m/%d/%Y') 
GROUP BY t2.empid,t2.catid
ORDER BY t2.empid,t2.catid;
```

Comment: Might want to include some sample data. You are comparing a string to a date with `date_format(dateIn, '%Y-%m-%d')>=str_to_date("1/01/2015", '%m/%d/%Y')`. You should always compare like types.

Answer (score 0):

When using `date_format` you are comparing strings so everything is getting messed up. I suggest you use `between` instead of two conditions like `date_field BETWEEN '2015-01-01' AND '2015-12-31'` and stick to the YYYY-MM-DD format.

```
SELECT
t4.firstname,
t1.category
,COUNT(t3.catid) as days
FROM category AS t1
LEFT JOIN (SELECT 
            DISTINCT empid,t1.catid 
        FROM attendance AS t2 
        LEFT JOIN category AS t1 ON (t1.catid>0)
        ) AS t2 
ON (t1.catid=t2.catid) 
LEFT JOIN attendance AS t3 ON (t2.empid=t3.empid AND t3.catid=t2.catid)
left join employee t4 on t2.empId=t4.empid
where
dateIn between '2015-01-01' and '2015-12-31'
GROUP BY t2.empid,t2.catid
ORDER BY t2.empid,t2.catid;
```

Comment: this is giving me the same result.

Comment: What type of field is dateIn? Can you share the result of `show create table TABLE_WITH_DATEIN_FIELD`